# Lost Folders and Files in the directory /home/ubuntu/ in Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, files, console

I have uploaded a `.tar` file in /home/ubuntu/ and un-zipped the file in the folder name 'analytics'. After reboot, I couldn't found the directory and the tar files. I have checked it through SSH session.

But however I have logged into VMware Vsphere console of the VM and I could able to view this files. Once after with the same session it also available in SSH session. I'm wondering of the issue, I have checked in Dmesg and syslog there is no errors.

After sometime it happens again like below as showing folder **Unreachable**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/analytics# cd ..
root@ubuntu:(unreachable)/#
```

Why it happens? Please provide any solutions..

Comment: Is /home/ubuntu automount partition? Is home folder encrypted ? In that case removing /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/auto-umount should help.

Comment: It's single partition under "/" `/dev/sda1 70G  1.7G   65G   3% /` And home folder is not encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

- What is the output of df?
- Try monitoring the directory using inotifywatch

  ```
  inotifywatch -v -e modify -e access -r /home/ubuntu/analytics
  ```

Comment: df output `rootfs                                                  49465136 8156612  38795784  18% /
udev                                                       10240       0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                     206128     604    205524   1% /run`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a permission problem. If you unpack a tarball as `root`, `tar(1)` restores not only permissions, but ***also*** users and groups. If this happened, no wonder you (as a regular user, presumably different from whoever owned the files) can't access them. Youd need to fix up owner/group, i.e., `sudo chown -R youruser:yourgroup /home/ubuntu/analytics`.

**Big Fat Warning:** ***Don't*** just follow instructions, particularly instructions to do something as `root` or using `sudo(1)` you read on random sites on the 'net without researching what they do.

Comment: I have logged in & unpacked `tar` file as `root` user and viewed as the same `root` user